# ASP .Net Entity Framework one database per user

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I'm making a web application that will be used by more than one company and I'd want each of them to have a separate database.

On the login screen the user would choose the company and it'll go to a separate database to fetch the connection string data.
The application is using code first so the database would be created with this new connection string if it doesn't already exist.

My approach was to store the connection string in the user's Session.

```
public MyContext() : base(MySession.Current.ConnectionString)
{
     Database.SetInitializer(new MyDevDbInitializer());    
}
```

I made a default connection string to be return in the case it can't fetch the session one.
This seems to work but I can see it goes for the default quite a few times on each request before getting the stored one. But the database creation and CRUD operations are working fine.

I don't know if I'm doing this the right way and if the other request done are important (I assume they are), those requests are done internally I can't seem to trace them.

Sorry for the long text. :)

Comment: I would caution you to not create the database automatically. I would have one context for the application, responsible migrating against a master database, and then another for user access that merely connects using an existing database. Then, you or your infrastructure team should create a database manually for a user when they create an account. Frankly it's frightening to have a web app creating databases on the fly, anyways, but you would also need to give the SQL user the web app connects with full instance permissions, which is a big security risk.

Comment: In addition to what @Chris Pratt wrote, think about making the data access layer so tight with ASP calling base(MySession.Current.ConnectionString). You have no control over creating or not a context with a wrong connection string. Also, you won't be able to write unit tests.

Comment: *one database per user* sounds like you need to seriously rethink your overall architecture. This sounds like a horribly bad design ....

Comment: I have one database per company not user sorry. Should I have only one database with the company identifier in each table then? It seems cleaner this way but I noticed it isn't easy to do although I got it working (mostly, all the business logic works fine and the database creation, only the user part and other operations done by the framework don't have the session in it). Anyway I started thinking this might not be good practice because I couldn't find anything online on how to do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is good to use 1 database for each company. And for user, you need to create a table that stores all informations for all users, it can be big enough, doesn't matter. I suggest to use 1 entity for multiple database: http://olivierhelin.com/blog/entity-framework/entity-framework-6-one-entity-data-model-multiple-databases-2

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) That means I'd have the users in separate databases then. I'd like to have it all together in a modular way. In any case if this works would it be possible to have this using code first?